# Facebook authentication from android using secret key and app id but not signature

Tags: android, facebook

Basically I am developing an android application which can post  updates to my facebook wall through my web application server. So actually my web application post my updates in facebook.  I am authorizing my android application like a webapp and not as a native android app. I downloaded the facebook for android SDK and tried examples by creating signature using keytool. I am able to post the updates from android as native app. From my web application, I am not able to post my updates through the access token I get.

I am not able to find an android example for facebook SDK which uses the secret key and app id for getting the access token.  Can you please give me some pointers on how to achieve the same using facebook SDK..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet but there is documentation online and it's quite clear:

You can find the description for al the methods at the following link 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/

You can also have a look at the code, if something isn't clear enough
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java

As far as I can tell you don't actually need the app secret in order to authenticate, only the app id. This is because it would be quite insecure to put the app secret on the phone(in the apk) since someone could retrieve it. So the resulting token will expire after a fairly short amount of time(couple of hours or so).

Also here's the complete guide to using the Facebook SDK on Android for authentication:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build